# Искать авторитет или авторитета?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование

Встретила 2 варианта окончания в афоризме "Только педанты во всем ищут авторитет" и "авторитета". Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Только педанты во всем ищут **авторитета** (Гете И.).  Имеется в виду, что в каждой области педанты ищут авторитетное лицо.

**АВТОРИТЕТ** 1. Общепризнанное значение, влияние. Иметь авторитет. 2. **Лицо, пользующееся признанием, влиянием.** Мнение авторитетов. Склоняться перед авторитетами. Быть авторитетом для кого-л.

Искать (кого?) ― авторитета (одушевленное существительное).